# Disabling Disqus reactions count

Tags: wordpress, disqus

I'm currently developing theme for Wordpress where I'm using Disqus.

How can I disable reactions link which is next to the comments? All instructions over the Internet are saying that I should disable reactions in Disqus settings, but there is not such a thing as reactions option in settings tab.

I'm looking for your help!

Comment: Just announced last week:  http://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/781086-reactions-have-been-discontinued

Comment: It seems that they just don't update Wordpress plugin yet, because it still shows up. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

We just removed this feature, as Dhaulagiri mentioned, which is why you can't edit the text as you did before - this will be removed by us very shortly. Since the text is served from Disqus globally, it won't require a plugin update to take effect.

If you need this done sooner than about a week, you can contact us and we can disable it: http://disqus.com/support/